# Excel chart with many lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In my dataset we have many groups writing content. We regualarly take a snapshop of the number of words written. Groups work over a five day Monday to Friday period and we're interested to chart their progress.

The data in excel looks like this (the last column is time+weekday to give a 'equivelent distance into the week' measurement)

```
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:40:19    35571   06/01/1900 09:40
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:50:20    35525   06/01/1900 09:50
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:30:20    35495   06/01/1900 09:30
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:20:19    35391   06/01/1900 09:20
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:10:18    35277   06/01/1900 09:10
trentham    07/07/2017  Friday  09:00:23    35258   06/01/1900 09:00
keele2  30/06/2017  Friday  18:00:12    29238   06/01/1900 18:00
keele2  30/06/2017  Friday  17:50:12    29236   06/01/1900 17:50
keele2  16/06/2017  Friday  18:00:13    29131   06/01/1900 18:00
keele2  16/06/2017  Friday  17:50:11    29111   06/01/1900 17:50
keele2  16/06/2017  Friday  12:50:11    28570   06/01/1900 12:50
```

If I make a scatter chart, I get this:

[image]

Which is okay, but I really want each group (in the example data: trentham and keele2) to have it's own line showing progress.  Is it possible to do this in Excel?

Full dataset is on [Dropbox here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7keyuoqjb8x16gn/Wordcounts.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You've plotted all your data as one very large series.

If you want to visualize different sections of your data differently, you need to define a different series for each section.  This is done most easily in the "Source Data..." dialog box:

[image]

Here, you can edit the data for an existing series, and also add new series.  Click on your single existing series in the Series list, and clear one of the boxes for X-values or Y-values.  Click the icon to the right of the box, and the dialog box will roll up to allow you to select the correct range of cells in your spreadsheet.

Select **only** the cells that correspond to Trentham.  Do the same for the other set of values.

And a new series, and repeat this process for Keele2 and any other sections of your data that you want to separate out.

With only series for Trentham and Keele2, your graph will look like this:

[image]

I hope this helps, and good luck.